# What is the tools name?pdf tools to show the contents

Tags: pdf

I found a pictures ,it can show a pdf files contents.so some one can tell me what's this software's name?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaA91.png)

Answer (score 0):

That is one of many [COS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49207768/what-does-cos-stand-for) viewers

iText call theirs [RUPS](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/rups)

in this case its [Adobe PreFlight](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/analyzing-documents-preflight-tool-acrobat.html)

[image]

Some are more graphic than others here is [one simple free viewer](https://www.o2sol.com/pdfxplorer/screenshots.htm) but I tend to use the one found in [Xchange PDF editor](https://help.tracker-software.com/pdfxe9/content-pane_ed.html), as it shows the target objects, but may need another to verify raw content.

[image]